# Load partial in existing page upon select combo box change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select combo box when upon changing, needs to load a specific html partial/page into a div on the same page as the select. I am new to Angular, so not really sure the best way to do this. I know how to do it using jQuery, how didn't know if this could be accomplished using a Directive.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue:

Using ng-include have the combo box change a url variable, i.e. 
    $scope.myPartialPath = "partials/template1.html".

Then have ng-include bind to the variable, i.e. 
    ng-include="myPartialPath"